# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.issuemanagement.repository.IssueHistoryRepository' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I get this error. What can be done in this case?

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> Description: Parameter 0 of constructor in com.issuemanagement.service.impl.IssueHistoryServiceImpl required a
> bean of type 'com.issuemanagement.repository.IssueHistoryRepository'
> that could not be found.
>
> Action: Consider defining a bean of type 'com.issuemanagement.repository.IssueHistoryRepository' in your
> configuration.

**IssueHistoryRepository.java**

```
public interface IssueHistoryRepository extends JpaRepository<IssueHistory, Long>{
    
}
```

**IssueHistoryService.java**

```
public interface IssueHistoryService {
    
    IssueHistory save(IssueHistory issueHistory);
    
    IssueHistory getById(Long id);
    
    Page<IssueHistory> getAllPageable(Pageable pageable);
    
    Boolean delete(IssueHistory issueHistory);
}
```

**IssueHistoryServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class IssueHistoryServiceImpl implements IssueHistoryService {

    
    private final IssueHistoryRepository issueHistoryRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public IssueHistoryServiceImpl(IssueHistoryRepository issueHistoryRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.issueHistoryRepository = issueHistoryRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }
   
    @Override
    public IssueHistory save(IssueHistory issueHistory) {
        if(issueHistory.getDate()==null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Issue cannot be null");
        }
        issueHistory = issueHistoryRepository.save(issueHistory);
        return issueHistory;
    }

    @Override
    public IssueHistory getById(Long id) {
        
        return issueHistoryRepository.getOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<IssueHistory> getAllPageable(Pageable pageable) {
        
        return issueHistoryRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean delete(IssueHistory issueHistory) {
        
        issueHistoryRepository.delete(issueHistory);
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

}
```

**IssueManagementApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.issuemanagement"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class IssueManagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IssueManagementApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper getModelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a no-args constructor of type IssueHistory(){} on your entity class , this may fix your problem

Comment: IssueHistory entity has @NoArgsConstructor from lombok

Comment: Have you defined your repository interface with @Repository annotation ?

Comment: No,. I add it now but I take same error:(

Comment: Can you upload your project on git so i can take a closer look , or give me a form of communication so i can help you with all your problems

Comment: try autowiring @Autowire this public IssueHistoryServiceImpl(IssueHistoryRepository issueHistoryRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.issueHistoryRepository = issueHistoryRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    } at IssueHistoryServiceImplementation

Comment: my git repo is github.com/derya26/spring-boot-issue-management.git thanks for your help @Arbis Malasi

Comment: @Arbis Malasi can you run the project?

Answer (score 0):

`@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project. Having said that, please drop `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from your main class as follows:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class IssueManagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IssueManagementApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper getModelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

Comment: Deleted these but same error exist

Comment: Try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` to `IssueManagementApplication` main class.